# Bind SystemTray.BackgroundColor

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone

I'm trying to change the SystemTray.BackgroundColor of my Windows Phone Application by binding it to a property in my ViewModel.
I've a property, which sets the Background of my Application.

```
    private SolidColorBrush _bgcolor;
    public SolidColorBrush BGColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _bgcolor;
        }
        set
        {
            _bgcolor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BGColor);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to set the BackgroundColor of the SystemTray to the same color as the BGColor. BGColor can be changed all the time & that's why I also want to change the SystemTray.BackgroundColor.
Anyway, I've tried to Bind the SystemTray in  like this:

```
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}"
```

Still, SystemTray Color is black. 
DataContext is set via a Locator

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Comment: If you needs to require notification took place, i think , source should be Dynamic Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding works, but the `SystemTray.BackgroundColor` is an Attached Property of type `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

So this will work:

```
public Color BGColor { get { return Colors.Orange; } }
```